# Can you extract information about a git object without cat-file?

Tags: windows, git, cmd

If you type "dir .git\objects /S /B" in CMD you can see all dirs, git objects and their hashes. Then if you type "more *remaining_38_symbols_of_hash*" inside of the appropriate directory, you get a weird output like:

```
☻Ед─lЖ┌╛°☼→SMмz⌂♠╒l2`l╡Y░2┘╨└└╠─D!/╡\пдвДс╚Гг/J♂r█"Ц?‼tg√ЄЫГ█>→кд$╡╕♦м╞БёQ╩ВЛw∟─╣fЮu╨`╛∙$Е⌂↨
Н╤)
```

Basically, how to get the info from an object without the "git cat-file" command or any external programming languages' libraries?

Comment: These (*loose* objects) are zlib compressed, so write yourself a zlib decompressor.

Comment: Note that there are also *packed* objects; their format is much less decipherable.

Comment: A good read from the Pro Git book : [Git Internals - Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)

Comment: Yes, I'd just read that. Aside of cat-file, the only way to read is to decompress a zlib object. Unfortunately, opening file with context manager and passing the file.read() to zlib.decompress() returns an encoded data:
b'tree 101\x0040000 bak\x00}\x8e_\xf0(\x954:\x8d\xf9R|\xb20\x01\x85<\xa0\xa9c100644 new.txt\x00\xc4\xe0\xc5\xe8upm\x86X\xa7\xe6\x11G\x06\xf4\xfb\x08\x0b?[100644 test.txt\x00@\x01\xe2d\xa0\xd1\xdc@\x17\n\x99\xcd@(\x03\xd9\xe4d\x0f\xba'
Any ideas how to decode those properly? cp1251 doesn't do it for me.

Comment: I mean, it does it for commits. But it doesn't do it for trees properly, the way cat-file does.

Comment: That's a *raw* tree object. Those are tuples with a funky encoding; see [here](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/githash.py).